# Padding discontinuous inputs in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using TensorFlow to train an lstm/rnn network. My input consists of a vector strings and I am predicting the next string in the sequence.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, num_steps], name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, num_steps], name='labels_placeholder')
```

Problem is, my input has a few 'breakpoints', during which there should be some padding, e.g.

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 break
11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18
19 break
```

Currently, I am feeding the network these vectors in a np.array (in batches).

```
data_x = np.zeros([batch_size, batch_partition_length], dtype=np.int32)
for i in range(batch_size):
    data_x[i] = raw_x[batch_partition_length * i:batch_partition_length * (i + 1)]
```

How do I fill in the np.array after 9 10? I know TensorFlow has a padding function, but I am unsure on how to use it, given that I feed it np.arrays.

```
tf.pad(tensor, paddings, mode='CONSTANT', name=None)
```